# Splitting parties into committees

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I feel like this should be an extremely simple problem, but I can't quite figure it out. How many ways are there to split $2n + 1$ places in a committee among $3$ nonempty parties, such that a coalition of any $2$ parties constitutes a majority? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the people distinguishable ? Are the parties distinguishable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be the number of places in parties one and two.

All that we need is $a,b\leq n$ and $a+b\geq n+1$

When $a$ is $0$ there are $0$ possibilites of $b$

When $a$ is $1$ there is $1$ possibility for $b$ (It must be $n$).

When $a$ is $2$ there are $2$ possibilities for $b$ (It can be $n$ or $n-1$)

$\dots$

When $a$ is $n$ there are $n$ possibilities for $b$ (It can be any number between $1$ and $n$ including $1$ and $n$).

Therefore there are $1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ways to split the places into parties.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this answer assumes parties are distinguishable and people in each party are not distinguishable.  Further it assumes that all people are assigned to some party.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. After looking at some textbooks I found this problem appears to be standard.